# Execute task before directory is loaded

Tags: ant

I have a `build.xml` with several `<taskdef>`s and `<target>`s. Furthermore, a `<property>` and a `<path>` are set:

```
<property name="foo" location="/some/path/elsewhere" />

<path id="foo.path">
    <fileset dir="${foo}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

One `<target>` trys to `<move>` (rename) directories which are under `foo.path`. This doesn't work because Ant already loaded that stuff, which blocks `<move>` on system level.

Is there a way to execute some sort of task *before* the directory in `<property>` and/or `<path>` is loaded?

**EDIT:** `<move>` task looks as follows:

```
<target name="moveDirs" if="some.condition">
    <move todir="/some/path_old">
        <fileset dir="/some/path"/>
    </move>
    <move todir="/some/path">
        <fileset dir="/some/path_new"/>
    </move>
</target>
```

Basically, I'm trying to rename `/some/path` to `/some/path_old` and `/some/path_new` to `/some/path`. As mentioned before, `foo.path` points to a folder under `/some/path`.

Comment: I don't believe Ant evaluates `<fileset>` or `<path>` objects before they're referenced by other tasks. Is it possible your `<move>` task is failing because there are files that are shared in both the `src` and `dest` of `<move>`?

Comment: @ChadNouis All files are part of the source (`dir`) as well as the destination (`todir`) because I use `<move>` to rename directories. I thought this is possible as of [version 1.6.3](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html): "the `file` attribute may be used to move (rename) an entire directory". Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're correct that `<move>` is the preferred way to rename directories. What does your `<move>` task look like?

Comment: @ChadNouis See edit (sorry, that should've been part of question from the beginning).